# Using tc traffic shaping to filter by ethtype

Tags: linux, traffic-shaping

I am trying to make a qdisc that filters out traffic based on its eth type and drops the specified traffic. However my current filter is not working and is not catching any traffic.

'# tc filter add dev eth2 prio 100 protocol all parent 1: u32 match u16 (eth type) (mask) at 12 flowid 1:2'

So my question is, how do I change my filter so that it picks up traffic based on eth type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference (at 0) is for the network part (layer 3). So to get the EtherType, it's right before the network layer [payload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Structure), at -2 (if considering an u16, or at -4 with an u32 and an adequate mask). So to match EtherType 0x9000 (called Loopback):

```
tc filter add dev eth2 prio 100 protocol all parent 1: u32 match u16 0x9000 0xffff at -2 flowid 1:2
```

which is equivalent to (and actually translated into):

```
tc filter add dev eth2 prio 100 protocol all parent 1: u32 match u32 0x00009000 0x0000ffff at -4 flowid 1:2
```

But actually this is overkill. The `protocol` parameter is already an EtherType filter here, so this is enough:

```
tc filter add dev eth2 prio 100 protocol 0x9000 parent 1: matchall flowid 1:2
```

If you want to drop it directly without any other processing, replace `flowid 1:2` with `action drop`.